# How do you remove all data after running syncdb?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7

I'm in production and just ran `syncdb` but I made a mistake and want to delete what `syncdb` did, including all data in the tables is fine. Just a fresh start in the databases so I can run `syncdb` again.

```
(virtualenv-2.7)[root@server mysite]# python manage.py sqlclear mainapp | python manage.py dbshell
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
app.comment: 'poster' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
app.myuser: The field named as the USERNAME_FIELD should not be included in REQUIRED_FIELDS on a swappable User model.
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using (MySQL, Postgres... etc)?

Comment: `drop database whatever_your_database_name; create databse whatever_your_database_name;`?

Comment: @Raja I just want to be able to run `syncdb` again

Comment: @Raja what do you mean? I've made some changes and want to populate them from fresh. I might try JOHN solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As J0HN stated in the comments, the best thing to do to start fresh was to actually just delete the database. I thought it might mess something up, but it won't. Simply login to mysql.

```
drop database whatever_your_database_name;
create databse whatever_your_database_name;
```

Then simply sync it again with `python manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 0):

Recreate database is probably the best way. Also you can do it using reset_db management command from [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) package.

Answer (score 0):

The Django 1.7 support [`migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/)
you just run `python manage.py migrate` again after edit.
more features to see: [release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its lazy, but I run:

```
django-admin.py reset_db --router=default --noinput
```